# Is it possible magento 2 + wordpress integration without third party extension?

Tags: magento2, wordpress, integration, blog

> Can we do integration of Magento 2 + WordPress  without using of third
>   party extension like Fishpig or any other?

Answer (score 1):

You can install WordPress in the subdirectory of your installation and connect it with a new database if you don't want to use any third party extension implementation.

But in this case, there are no configuration options available in the Magento admin like with extension.

Comment: it means sharing only db. but how can we use wordpress function in all over magento ?

Comment: I've done it on one of my websites. Your WordPress installation is separate and you can not use WordPress functions in Magento file system.